# Prevent incoming phone calls from disconnecting Google Hangouts / Meet

Tags: settings, calls

If I'm on a Google Hangouts Call or Google Meet call and a phone call comes in, it kicks me off without giving me an option.  Is there a way to control this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I have found that if you are on a wi-fi network, you can turn on airplaine mode, which disables your calls.  Then re-enable wi-fi and connect to Hangouts Meet.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior can be prevented by enabling do not disturb mode while on the hangouts call.

That by itself is a manual solution, but you could use Tasker (or a similar app) to automatically enable / disable do not disturb when Hangouts is open.